# Call saveCell on jqGrid blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've made a custom radio button element for jqGrid, and it works fine, but I'm not able to call saveCell method when I click outside the grid.

HTML Code:

```
    {  name : 'radioelement',
       index : '1',
       editable : true,
       edittype: "custom",
       editoptions : {custom_element: yesNoRadioElem, custom_value: yesNoRadioValue}
},
```

Javascript Code:

```
function yesNoRadioElem(value, options){
    var result = "";
    var radioName = "radio_"+options.name;
    if(value == null){
        value = false;
    }

    result += "<div><label>" + $.pf.locale.yesNoRadioTrue + "</label><input type='radio' name='" + radioName + "' value='True' ";
    if (value==="True"){
        result += " checked ";
    }
    result +=  "/></div>";

    result += "<div><label>" + $.pf.locale.yesNoRadioFalse + "</label><input type='radio' name='" + radioName + "' value='False' ";
    if (value==="False"){
        result += " checked ";
    }
    result +=  "/></div>";


    return result; 
}

function yesNoRadioValue(elem, operation, value){
    if (operation === 'get') {
        var result = $(elem).find("input:checked");
        if (result.length > 0){
            return result.val();
        }
        else{
            return "";
        }
    } else if (operation === 'set') {
        if ($(elem).is(':checked') === false) {
            $(elem).filter('[value=' + value + ']').attr('checked', true);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to set up this new element to call saveCell() when I click outside the grid? It's only called when I click on another row.